# How to get X-axis values correctly ordered?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following example.

```
#Reproducible example 
data = data.frame(matrix(nrow = 20,ncol = 3))
colnames(data) = c("Type","Subtype","Value")
data$Type = rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"),2)
data$Subtype = c(rep(c("X"),10),rep("Y",10))
a = sample(c(51:100),10,replace = TRUE)
b = a - sample(c(21:40),10,replace = TRUE)
a1 = 0
b1 = 0
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(data$Subtype[i]=="X"){
    a1 = a1 + 1
    data$Value[i] = a[a1]
  } else{
    b1 = b1+1
    data$Value[i] = b[b1]
  }
}
library(ggplot2)
plot_1 = ggplot(data=data,aes(x = reorder(Type, Value), y = Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(colour=Subtype))
plot_1

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
   
data_wide = pivot_wider(data,id_cols = "Type",names_from = "Subtype",
                        values_from = "Value")
plot_2 = ggplot(data_wide) +
  geom_point(aes(x = reorder(Type,X), y = X)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = reorder(Type,X), y = Y))
plot_2
```

As you might observe, in plot_1, ordering on X-axis is not correct or need not be correct.
In plot_2, ordering is correct, but I am not able to connect X and Y values for each type using geom_line.
I need help in either getting order correct in case of plot_1 or how to connect points using line in plot_2.

Comment: Try `reorder(Type, Value, max)` for plot_1. Currently `reorder` is using the `mean` (default) for each `Subtype`.